# How to check if Cursor Expression(select cursor) is returning null?

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor, expression, oracle11gr2

I've a select cursor expression with multiple inner select cursors. I wanted to check in the outer most select cursor if the inner cursor is returning any value or not.
eg.,

```
SELECT
CURSOR
  (SELECT
   CURSOR
     (SELECT c.cat_name category ,
      CURSOR
        (SELECT
         CURSOR
           (SELECT grp.grpng
            GROUPING ,
                             grp.action_group action_group ,
            CURSOR
              (SELECT
               CURSOR
                 (SELECT header_id ,
                         order_no ,
                         cust_name ,
                         cust_phone ,
                         org ,
                         status `enter code here`,
                         reason
                  FROM headers h
                  WHERE h.header_id = da.header_id ) "G_HEADER"
               FROM dual) "LIST_G_HEADER"
            FROM action_group grp
            WHERE grp.grpng = da.grpng
              AND grp.action_grp = da.action_grp ) "G_ACTION"
         FROM action_rep da
         WHERE da.org = 'test'
           AND da.cat_id = c.cat_id
         ORDER BY category,
         GROUPING,
                  reason ) "LIST_G_ACTION_GROUP"
      FROM dual ) "G_CATEGORY"
   FROM dual ) "LIST_G_CATEGORY" ,
       c.category_name
FROM cat c
ORDER BY c.cat_name
```

I need to put a check to see if the result of "LIST_G_CATEGORY" cursor is null or not and if it is null then do not display that row.
P.S: please ignore the column name mismatches as the query is made up in rush to post here.

Version: Oracle 11g R2

Comment: You "made up in rush" but this represents an actual piece of business logic? What is the reason for this baroque nesting of scalar cursors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to check whether the cursor is *empty or not*, one should `fetch` it first.

This means that you could crate a `function` (probably using `SYS_REFCURSOR`) that will return `1` or `0` accordingly, when the `cursor` is empty or not - but you should be aware of the `rowtype` that the `cursor` returns, in order to do that.

Check this references

[oracle cursor expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions005.htm),

[similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814111/how-to-check-if-cursor-returns-any-records-in-oracle),

[check sys ref cursor is empty - stackoverflw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058245/best-way-to-check-if-sys-refcursor-is-empty),

[ref cursor rowcount question](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:96612348060).